# if (div/class equals){.click}

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm kinda fresh in this and not even sure if my question is correct :D so:
I wanted to make a script that .click something if (div id/class) == its title:

```
<div id="health_bar_pointer" class="row health_bar" title="Punkty życia: 632350 -> 100%">
                <div class="fleft current_health" style="width: 88%;"></div>
```

so I tried something like this:

```
if ($('health_bar_pointer').text () =="Punkty życia: 632350 -> 100%"){
        setTimeout(function(){$('#item_menu_game_attack.last').click();
                                      ;}, 4000);
}
```

or other compilations of this. I don't need a full code, or something, just a site where I can find the answer for my problem!

Comment: Missing `#` from `$('health_bar_pointer')`. Example `$('#health_bar_pointer')`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all the div elements whose class/id is same as the title, you can use `.filter()` function along with attribute selector like this,

```
var divs = $("div").filter(function () {
    return $(this).attr("class") == $(this).attr("title") || $(this).attr("id") == $(this).attr("title")
});
divs.addClass("test");
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lv5cn8xy/140/)

Answer (score 0):

so, basically you want to intercept click on specific element or anywhere. And then you want to see, if the clicked element's `title` and `innerText` are equal or not.
below code traps click on any div on the page:

```
$('body').on('click', 'div', function(e){

     var $this = $(this);
     var a = $this.attr('title');
     var txt = $(this).text();
     if(a==txt){

          //do whatever you want to
          setTimeout(function(){
                      $('#item_menu_game_attack:last').click();
           ;}, 4000);
     }
});
```

hope this helps